# How to vertically align text in html/css?

Tags: html, css, center

I am working on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy0mz2Lv/61/embedded/result) in which I want to vertically align James text in html/css as shown below in the image. The HTML code which I have used for that is:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="reviews" style="display: block;">
   <p>
      <span class="heading_size">reviews:</span>
   </p>
   <p class="text-justify mb-0 mb-1">
   </p>
   <div class="review">
      <div class="mb-2 renter_review">
         <div class="renter_rating_image">
            <img class="item_review_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
         </div>
         <p style="text-align:center;font-style:italic;margin-bottom:0%;">this bobcat was amazing</p>
         <span>10.22,07, 04, 18</span>
      </div>
      <div class="renter_review_firstname">James</div>
   </div>
   <div class="review">
      <div class="mb-2 renter_review">
         <div class="renter_rating_image">
            <img class="item_review_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
         </div>
         <p style="text-align:center;font-style:italic;margin-bottom:0%;">it was perfect!</p>
         <span>10.14,01, 17, 18</span>
      </div>
      <div class="renter_review_firstname">James</div>
   </div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

In the fiddle, the text **James** is not properly aligned. I am wondering what changes I need to do in the HTML/CSS code so that the text James is aligned vertically properly.

I have a feeling width of **this bobcat was amazing** and **it was perfect** text is making James text not properly aligned vertically.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to do **HTML/CSS code** so that James text is properly **vertically aligned**.

At this moment, as shown in the image below,  the upper **James text** is quite right in comparison to the **lower James** text.

[image]

Comment: @Jonathan No they are not duplicate. The topic of the question remains the same but they both are different.

Comment: Use a grid system like bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Try: .renter_review_firstname{align-self:center;}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution, or another now we have a GRID also.

This solution, is to wrapping the content of your container with `review` class, and use flexbox for what you want.

```css
.wrapper-review {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane" id="reviews" style="display: block;">
   <p>
      <span class="heading_size">reviews:</span>
   </p>
   <p class="text-justify mb-0 mb-1">
   </p>
   <div class="wrapper-review">
    <div class="review">
      <div class="mb-2 renter_review">
         <div class="renter_rating_image">
            <img class="item_review_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
         </div>
         <p style="text-align:center;font-style:italic;margin-bottom:0%;">this bobcat was amazing</p>
         <span>10.22,07, 04, 18</span>
      </div>
      <div class="renter_review_firstname">James</div>
   </div>
   <div class="review">
      <div class="mb-2 renter_review">
         <div class="renter_rating_image">
            <img class="item_review_image" src="https://i.imgur.com/lbDo4tM.jpg">
         </div>
         <p style="text-align:center;font-style:italic;margin-bottom:0%;">it was perfect!</p>
         <span>10.14,01, 17, 18</span>
      </div>
      <div class="renter_review_firstname">James</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding the following to your css

```
p {
   width: min-content;
}
```

But you should try using a grid system like http://getbootstrap.com. It helps a ton! :)